# Unity3d Input System, Specifying a time for a button to become active again

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My character jumps when I press the "space" key. I want to prevent the player from constantly spamming "space". Is there a feature to deactivate that key for a certain period of time after pressing a key on the Input System?

I tried using coroutine to solve this problem, but I couldn't understand whether it made sense.

https://ibb.co/0MW6qCB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a cooldown or delay to prevent the player from jumping frequently - via coroutine

**simple example**

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float jumpForce = 10f;
    public float jumpCooldown = 1f; // Adjust this cooldown value as needed

    private bool canJump = true;

    void Update()
    {
        // Check for user input, e.g., the "space" key
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canJump)
        {
            StartCoroutine(JumpCooldown());
            Jump();
        }
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        // logic here
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, jumpForce);
    }

    IEnumerator JumpCooldown()
    {
        canJump = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(jumpCooldown);
        canJump = true;
    }
}
```

here  `JumpCooldown` coroutine is responsible for setting `canJump` to `false`, waiting for the specified cooldown duration `jumpCooldown`, then setting `canJump` back to `true`. During the cooldown period, player won't be able to jump even if  "space" key pressed .If you prefer not to use coroutines, you can track the last time the player jumped to achieve a similar effect using timestamps , please consider the following

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float jumpForce = 10f;
    public float jumpCooldown = 1f; // change cooldown value as needed

    private bool canJump = true;
    private float lastJumpTime = 0f;

    void Update()
    {
        // Check for user input, e.g., the "space" key
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && CanJump())
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        // logic here
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, jumpForce);

        // Update the last jump time
        lastJumpTime = Time.time;
    }

    bool CanJump()
    {
        // Check if enough time has passed since the last jump
        return canJump && Time.time - lastJumpTime > jumpCooldown;
    }
}
```

`CanJump` function checks if enough time has passed since the last jump. If it has, the player can jump. update the last jump time after a successful jump via The Jump function

**Updated example using Unity Input System**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float jumpForce = 10f;
    public float jumpCooldown = 1f;

    private float lastJumpTime;

    void Update()
    {
        if (ShouldJump())
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }

    private bool ShouldJump()
    {
        // Check if the Jump action is triggered and if enough time has passed since the last jump
        return Keyboard.current.spaceKey.wasPressedThisFrame && Time.time - lastJumpTime > jumpCooldown;
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        //jump logic
        Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (rb != null)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
            lastJumpTime = Time.time;
        }
    }
}
```

make sure `Rigidbody2D` is attached to your player GameObject for physics interactions. The `ShouldJump` method checks if  space key was pressed this frame and if enough time has passed since the last jump. If both conditions are met, it calls the Jump method, which applies a vertical force to the player's `Rigidbody2D`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is a useful code. But the system I use is "Input System". I wonder if this feature is available on this system. Thank you again.

https://ibb.co/0MW6qCB

Comment: @doguKu You are welcome , I've updated my answer with  Unity Input System example in the last section of my answer

Comment: This worked, thank you :)

Comment: @doguKu you are welcome , Please mark my answer as accepted , Thank you